# How to get bibex citations as [Gaz14-ol] for online references?

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex, bibtex, biblatex

I want to get online references to appears as [Gaz14-ol] or [MQT21-ol] or [GPP+20-ol] while i get [Gaz14] or [MQT21].
[image]

```
@misc{Latex5,
    author = {Gazebo},
    title = {{Open Source Robotics Foundation}},
    howpublished = "\url{http://gazebosim.org/}",
    year = {2014}, 
    note = "[Online; accessed 04-Apr-2021]"
}

@misc{Latex6,
    author = {MQTT},
    title = {{The Standard for IoT Messaging}},
    howpublished = "\url{https://mqtt.org/}",
    year = {2021}, 
    note = "[Online; accessed 04-Apr-2021]"
}
```

I am using texstudio, and bibliographystyle{literature/myalphadin} bibliography style *alphadin* and bibgerm package. A very short sample of how my document looks like:

```
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\begin{document}
\restoregeometry
\bibliographystyle{literature/myalphadin}
\bibliography{literature/literature}
\nocite{*}
\rmfamily
\end{document}
```

Usually the citation takes the first 3 author surname, followed by the year. However, for online citations i need a -ol at the end. Any suggestions or leads about how to get this will be very helpful.

The template I am using can be found here:-
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G6uWvW-j13BUo9xG07Vl2NTSqjWOyEF2?usp=sharing

Alphadin.bst file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_QQXf8QufsvXpd65z5UNY7cczGBu9mGE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please make a [mre]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz can you please help me how to achieve [-ol] at the end?

Comment: Not without seeing a [mre]. We don't even know which bibliography tool you use, since you added both the bibtex and biblatex tags.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Thank you for the reply, I have added more details, does this help? I am not very experienced with latex so maybe it seems like a beginner-level question. Please let me know if need more info. is needed. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: We don't have access to your local files. Please remove all the ones not needed to reproduce the problem or make them available to us. The title page surely is irrelevant to the bibliography, no? However the bibliographystyle is crucial to your question.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, you can find the template here: - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G6uWvW-j13BUo9xG07Vl2NTSqjWOyEF2?usp=sharing , if you can please help me as to how to produce the needed citations. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share `myalphadin.bst`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz , https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_QQXf8QufsvXpd65z5UNY7cczGBu9mGE/view?usp=sharing , You can find it here, many thanks !

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I would really appreciate if you could help me with this, as I am stuck. Many Thanks!